# BASIC, how lines were stored in memory?

Tags: language-design, basic

As I understand BASIC had line numbers because at the time you had to use a line editor to input your program. It allowed you to do something like this:

```
20 END
10 PRINT "HELLO WORLD"
```

This program would print `"HELLO WORLD"`. My question is how did BASIC allow you to enter lines this way? How were they stored in memory? I suppose it was a map of line numbers and pointers to lines themselves which was updated every time you input a line. But this map would have to be sorted before running a `LIST`/`RUN` command. Is that so? If not then how exactly did BASIC store commands in the memory?

Comment: I don't actually know, but I'd assume they'd use something like a BST-based map, which is sorted automatically. That is, items are inserted in such a way, that the map is always sorted.

Comment: @sepp2k, thanks! BST was invented in sixties and Microsoft BASIC was created in 75 so quite possibly that's what they used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess each Basic implementation used a particular approach.

The Basic I grew up with was a Microsoft Basic running on the MSX computer. According to "The MSX Red Book" which I read avidly at the time, the MS-Basic actually used a linear list.

Each Basic line was stored as a pointer to the next line, followed by its actual line number in binary form, followed by the tokenized version of the line and followed by a null char; something like this:

```
    Address  | Content
    8000     | 8009 -- next line
    8002     | 10   -- this line number
    8004     | .... -- opcodes for each instruction in the line
    ...      | ...
    8007     | ...
    8008     | Null -- terminator
    8009     | ...  -- the next line
```

Despite the fact that the lines where a linked list, the Basic interpreter didn't take advantage of that. Each line was physically stored in linear succession.

As you can imagine, inserting and deleting lines in the middle of an existing program represented a lot of work. If new lines where inserted between existing ones the subsequent lines were moved up in memory to make room for the new one(s). Likewise, deleting lines mid-program would cause the subsequent lines being moved down in memory to fulfill the space left by the removed one(s). This moving up and down the memory meant that all those links had to be updated for each line moved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I started suspecting some version of BASIC should have used linked lists as they are very logical and (I suppose) quite efficient for the task

Comment: The interpreter took at least some advantage: searching a line for deleting, changing, or for inserting a new line, and also for executing, is faster by traversing the links than by scanning the whole program memory for the zero bytes that mark the end of lines.